# Moment.js not accepting query string as valid input

Tags: javascript, http, get, momentjs

I have the following GET function that converts a query string into a moment (or Date) object. I've run a bunch of tests and **basically moment.js doesn't seem to accept req.query.m as a valid string**. Moment works fine if I hardcode the input, and I'm able to get the query string itself.

The query string is:

> http://localhost:8080/file/newCalendar?m=1455910939

```
app.get('/file/newCalendar', function(req, res) {
    var dateSelect = req.query.m;
    var selectedDate = moment(req.query.m);
    var selectedMonth = selectedDate.month();

    jsontest = {
      'testQuery': dateSelect,
      'testMomentOnQuery': moment(req.query.m),
      'testMomentOnVariable': moment(dateSelect),    
      'testMomentMonth': moment(12345678).month(),
    };

res.json(jsontest);
})
```

I've also tried using Date() instead of moment.

```
 app.get('/file/newCalendar', function(req, res) {
    var selectedDate = Date(req.query.m);
    var selectedMonth = selectedDate.getMonth();

    jsontest = {
      'selectedDate': selectedDate,
      'selectedMonth': selectedMonth,
    };

res.json(jsontest);
})
```

Date() works fine but instead the .getMonth() function gets

> TypeError: selectedDate.getMonth is not a function at Object.handle

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really should mark this as answered, or close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using moment(parseInt(req.query.m))

Also you can use moment(req.query.m, 'x')
2nd parameter is the format string. X for seconds, x for milliseconds since 1970.(unix ts)